# python: better workaround for treating argument in bash/cmd line as an object

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am passing args like

```
python file.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

I want to know if there is a way to treat these args as objects not strings for the following code:

```
one = sys.argv[1]
two = sys.argv[2]
three = sys.argv[3]
from one import two
    a = two.three()
```

since one two three would be strings. how can they be parsed as objects?

UPDATE:

```
pkg = import_module(two, package=one)
```

gives

```
__import__(name)                                                              
ImportError: No module named <whatever_module_name>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [importlib for Python 2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) or [importlib for Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).

```
import importlib
path = importlib.import_module('os.path')
print(path.join('a','b'))
```

Comment: what is a and b? I have imported using this lib the module. now i want to access a function named three which is given as an argument

Comment: In the concrete example you have given you could use `getattr(importlib.import_module(one+'.'+two), three)()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `__import__` or the `imp` [module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) to import object programmatically:

```
# Import 'name' relative to 'path'
module = imp.load_module(name, *imp.find_module(name, [path]))
```

Whenever I've wanted to programmatically import modules, this is how I do it, but `imp.find_module` returns a 3-tuple:

```
fil, path, desc = imp.find_module(name, [path])
module = imp.load_module(name, fil, path, desc)
```

Comment: what is * for in *imp?

Comment: It's argument unpacking. I'll edit the answer to make it a little more clear

Comment: ok yea i just read the find_module lib and saw it returns in tuple form. but then when it returns a tuple of 3, couldn't we just do it w/o * ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but since I generally don't need to access the `file`, `path` and `description`, I usually just pass them into `load_module` unpacked. A closer reading of the docs says we have to close the `file`, so best to do it multi-line. Ultimately, `imp` is more powerful and nuanced, but `__import__` also works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is [`__importing__`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__).

```
spam = __import__('spam', globals(), locals(), [], 0)
```